# pyspark write dataframe to hbase ,integer values are loading as bytes

Tags: pyspark, hbase

Do we have any option to convert integer values to integer only while writing dataframe to hbase through pyspark ,by default while writing dataframe to hbase integer values are converting to byte type in hbase table?

```
Below is the code:
    catalog2 = {
        "table": {"namespace": "default","name": "trip_test1"},
        "rowkey": "key1",
        "columns": {
        "serial_no": {"cf": "rowkey","col": "key1","type": "string"},
        "payment_type": {"cf": "sales","col": "payment_type","type":"string"},
        "fare_amount": {"cf": "sales","col": "fare_amount","type": "string"},
        "surcharge": {"cf": "sales","col": "surcharge","type": "string"},
        "mta_tax": {"cf": "sales","col": "mta_tax","type": "string"},
        "tip_amount": {"cf": "sales","col": "tip_amount","type": "string"},
        "tolls_amount": {"cf": "sales","col": "tolls_amount","type":"string"},
        "total_amount": {"cf": "sales","col": "total_amount","type": "string"}
    }
}

import json

cat2=json.dumps(catalog2)

df.write.option("catalog",cat2).option("newtable","5").format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save()
```

output:

```
\x00\x00\x03\xE7 column=sales:payment_type, timestamp=1529495930994, value=CSH
\x00\x00\x03\xE7 column=sales:surcharge, timestamp=1529495930994, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x03\xE7 column=sales:tip_amount, timestamp=1529495930994, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x03\xE7 column=sales:tolls_amount, timestamp=1529495930994, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x03\xE7 column=sales:total_amount, timestamp=1529495930994, value=@!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x03\xE8 column=sales:fare_amount, timestamp=1529495930994, value=@\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x03\xE8 column=sales:mta_tax, timestamp=1529495930994, value=?\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

expected output:

```
999 column=sales:fare_amount, timestamp=1529392479358, value=8.0
999 column=sales:mta_tax, timestamp=1529392479358, value=0.5
999 column=sales:payment_type, timestamp=1529392479358, value=CSH
999 column=sales:surcharge, timestamp=1529392479358, value=0.0
999 column=sales:tip_amount, timestamp=1529392479358, value=0.0
999 column=sales:tolls_amount, timestamp=1529392479358, value=0.0
999 column=sales:total_amount, timestamp=1529392479358, value=8.5
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. HBase stores only byte arrays - your application is responsible to convert the data on reading. It seems that the output you have posted comes from hbase-shell, which obviously shows only byte arrays.

Comment: while writing dataframe as hbase table,integer values are being converted to    bytes,is there any other way to get them only in integer values in hbase table  by modifying df.write command given above.

Answer (score 0):

The numeric values will convert to bytes then get stored in Hbase. You have to use same library(in your case "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase") to get exact values while in reading from Hbase.

If you want to store values as numeric in Hbase, convert data type of column as string type and store it as the library "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase" won't convert string to bytes.

Make sure data type of column value and catalog type is same to get better result.